# Solving equations bounded by a region

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

**Straight to the point**

I have a function

```
DiracPoint[{theta_, phi_}] :=

 Module[{c1, c2, c3, x, y, cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4},
  (*Define c_j*)
  {c1, c2, c3} = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1,2,3};
  (*excludes points with no solution*)
  If[0 <= ((c2 + c3)^2 - c1^2)/(4 c2 c3) <= 1,
   cond1 = (c2 + c3) Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] == -c1 Cos[3 y/2];(*Re[f]=0*)
   cond2 = (c2 - c3) Sin[Sqrt[3] x/2] == c1 Sin[3 y/2];(*Im[f]=0*)
   cond3 = Abs[y] <= 2 Pi/3;(*Bound x within hexagon*)
   cond4 = Abs[x] <= (4 Pi/3 - Abs[y])/Sqrt[3];(*Bound y within hexagon*)
   {x, y}/.Solve[cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4, {x, y}]
   , Null]
  ]
```

which needs modifying to run successfully and quickly for all angles in the range `0<=theta<=Pi` and `0<=phi<=2Pi`. Non-exact and numerical solutions are absolutely fine. At the minute this function only works for a few values of exact input. Otherwise Solve fails to work, or it takes forever to run. Any suggestions? The function should (I believe) return two sets of coordinates {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}, or Null, or for a few special angles more than 2 sets of coordinates.

**Extra details if needed**

I'm trying to develop a Mathematica function which finds the $(x,y)$ solutions to the equation $f=0$ in a region of space bounded by a hexagon centered at the origin, with side length $4\pi/3\sqrt{3}$ as shown below. The function is

$f=\mathcal{C}_1 \exp(-iy)+\mathcal{C}_2 \exp(-\sqrt{3}ix/2) + \mathcal{C}_3 \exp(-\sqrt{3}ix/2)$

where $\mathcal{C}_j = 1-3\sin^2\theta\cos^2(\phi-2\pi(j-1)/3)$ and the bounding region of space is

[image]

As $f=0$ implies we also need $Re[f]=0$ and $Im[f]=0$, satisfying $f=0$ is equivalent to satisfying the two equations:

$(\mathcal{C}_2 + \mathcal{C}_3)\cos(\sqrt{3}x/2)=-\mathcal{C}_1\cos(3y/2)$

$(\mathcal{C}_2 - \mathcal{C}_3)\sin(\sqrt{3}x/2)=\mathcal{C}_1\cos(3y/2)$

So I desire a function `DiracPoint[{theta_,phi_}]` which (quickly) returns the set of coordinates `{x,y}` that satisfy the above requirements. I have tried various approaches, but I keep running into problems of wrong or incomplete solutions, or exact methods taking forever to compute. Successful development of this function will aid with research that develops on this paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5005.pdf) (should be publicly available). It's possible to find analytical solution for a given $(\theta,\phi)$ but a numerical solution will help greatly with visualisation.

Many thanks for any and all help.

Comment: `cc = {c1, c2, c3} = 
   1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3};
v = {E^(-I y), E^(-Sqrt@3/2 I x), E^(-Sqrt@3/2 I x)};
f = cc.v;
llr = Re[TrigExpand@f // ExpToTrig] /. __ + Re[x_] :> x;
lli = Im[TrigExpand@f // ExpToTrig] /. Im[__] + x_ :> x /. 
   Re -> Identity;
Reduce[{lli == 0 && llr == 0}, {x, y}]`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Although I copied and pasted this into Mathematica 10 and it delivered the result 'False' so doesn't quite seem to be working for me.

Comment: Have you tried starting a fresh Mma session?

Comment: Yes, it finds some kind of solution when theta and phi are undefined, but choosing a value for these parameters Reduce gives `False`. The code provided also doesn't take into account the requirement that solutions are bounded by the hexagon, but one task at a time I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to `Solve` using `cond1` and `cond2` only, then keep only those answers that satisfy `cond3` and `cond4`.  For instance,

```
DiracPoint[{theta_, phi_}] := Module[{c1, c2, c3, x, y, cond1, cond2},
    {c1, c2, c3} = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3};
    Cases[If[0 <= ((c2 + c3)^2 - c1^2)/(4 c2 c3) <= 1,
       cond1 = (c2 + c3) Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] == -c1 Cos[3 y/2];
       cond2 = (c2 - c3) Sin[Sqrt[3] x/2] == c1 Sin[3 y/2];
       {x, y} /. Solve[cond1 && cond2 , {x, y}], Null], {z1_, z2_} /; 
       Abs[z2] <= 2 Pi/3 && Abs[z1] <= (4 Pi/3 - Abs[z2])/Sqrt[3], Infinity]]
```

Sample results are

```
DiracPoint[{.1, .8}]
(* {{-1.20893, -2.07923}, {1.20893, 2.07923}} *)

DiracPoint[{1, 1}]
(* {} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This appears to be working a treat. Will report back after more tinkling.